# What is the opposite of the QUOTENAME function?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In SQL Server there is a built in function that quotes an identifier for you called [QUOTENAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Is there a function that does the opposite and removes the quotes again?

In other words what do I replace SOMEFUNCTION with in the following code example to get it to return 1 for any value I could initialize @name to?

```
declare @name nvarchar(50) = 'hello]'

select 
    case 
        when SOMEFUNCTION(QUOTENAME(@name)) = @name then 1
        else 0
    end
```

Comment: http://www.rmjcs.com/SQLServer/TSQLFunctions/UnQuoteName/tabid/832/Default.aspx

Comment: @GolezTrol you should really make an answer from that, including the code and the link.

Comment: How about [`QUOTENAME('Thomas', '''') `](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) or `QUOTENAME('Thomas', '"')`? First example uses `'` the second `"` as quotation characters, both valid options for `QUOTENAME`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`PARSENAME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx):

```
declare @name sysname = quotename('foo]');
print @name;
set @name = parsename(@name, 1);
print @name;


[foo]]]
foo]
```

Comment: Works well for the purpose I need it for. But it only works for square brackets and double quotes. 'SELECT PARSENAME(QUOTENAME('hello]',''''),1);' gives a null result (tested on SQL Server 2008 R2).

Answer (score 0):

First, create a SQL function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.[Revert_QUOTENAME](@quotedvalue As VARCHAR(8000)) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(8000)
As 
BEGIN
    RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@quotedvalue, 2, LEN(@quotedvalue) - 2), ']]', ']')
END
```

Then,

```
declare @name nvarchar(50) = 'hello]'

select 
    case 
        when [Revert_QUOTENAME](QUOTENAME(@name)) = @name then 1
        else 0
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use case when logic to remove the quotes or brackets.

```
DECLARE @yourTable TABLE (names VARCHAR(15));
INSERT INTO @yourTable VALUES('hello]'),('[hello]]'),('"hello]"');

SELECT  names AS QuotenameVal,
        CASE
            WHEN LEFT(names,1) = '"'
                 AND RIGHT(names,1) = '"'
                THEN SUBSTRING(names,2,LEN(names) - 2)
            WHEN LEFT(names,1) = '['
                 AND RIGHT(names,1) = ']'
                THEN SUBSTRING(names,2,LEN(names) - 2)
            ELSE names
        END Actual_Value
FROM @yourTable
```

Results:

```
QuotenameVal    Actual_Value
--------------- ---------------
hello]          hello]
[hello]]        hello]
"hello]"        hello]
```

Answer (score 0):

CODE;

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[funObtenerSinQuoteName]
(@vchrCadena VARCHAR(8000) , @vchrQuoteNameIni CHAR(1),@vchrQuoteNameFin CHAR(1))  

RETURNS VARCHAR(8000) AS  
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @vchrSubCadena VARCHAR (8000), @intCharIndexIni INT,@intCharIndexFin INT

    SET @intCharIndexIni=CHARINDEX(@vchrQuoteNameIni,@vchrCadena,0)
    SET @intCharIndexFin=CHARINDEX(@vchrQuoteNameFin,@vchrCadena,0)
    SET @vchrSubCadena=LTRIM(RTRIM(SubString(@vchrCadena,@intCharIndexIni+1,@intCharIndexFin-@intCharIndexIni-1)))

    RETURN @vchrSubCadena
END
```

Comment: I suggest you to improve your example by reading the [Minimal, Complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).