# Idempotent QUOTENAME()?

Tags: t-sql

The QUOTENAME() function in tsql is oft used when building dynamic sql to handle "special" charatcers within names. If one winds up with redundant calls via nested code it falls apart.

```
declare @name sysname = 'simple_name'
print '@name:    ' + @name
print 'QUOTENAME(@name):        ' + QUOTENAME(@name)
print 'QUOTENAME(QUOTENAME(@name)): ' + QUOTENAME(QUOTENAME(@name))
```

The results

> @name:     simple_name
>   QUOTENAME(@name):     [simple_name]
>   QUOTENAME(QUOTENAME(@name)): [[simple_name]]]

Other than making sure these sort of chained calls are impossible within a codebase, has anyone a idempotent version of that is safe even for nested calls?

Comment: You are in trouble if you don't know whether your input has been sanitized or not. You should "make sure these sort of chained calls are impossible within a codebase".

Comment: It's impossible to have an idempotent version of `quotename` because it is legal to have a raw name that looks like an escaped name (e.g. already with brackets around it). Depending on [what you actually want](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147640), you might get away with [passing your data to `parsename`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30302108/11683) and looking at exactly how it's different from what you believe to be a raw name.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know regex very well, but I'd imagine you could do some kind of @sql scrub before the exec.

I'm sure some kind of regex would be quicker, but here is my test.

```
DECLARE @name sysname = 'simple_name'
DECLARE @SQLTest nvarchar(max)

SET @SQLTest = 'select QUOTENAME(QUOTENAME(@name)), ''blah'', ''blah'''

SET @SQLTest = Replace(@SQLTest, Substring(@SQLTest, PatIndex('%QUOTENAME(QUOTENAME(%))%', @SQLTest), 20), 'QUOTENAME(')


SET @SQLTest = Replace(@SQLTest, Substring(@SQLTest, PatIndex('%))%', @SQLTest), 2), ')')
```

--- this might be a safer second replace?

```
SET @SQLTest = Replace(@SQLTest, Substring(reverse(@SQLTest), PatIndex('%))%EMANETOUQ%', reverse(@SQLTest)), 2), ')')
```

-

```
select @SQLTest

exec sp_executesql @SQLTest, N'@name sysname', @name
```

Comment: That's a good thought. I wasn't clear enough in the question using the immediately nested quotename to show the point. In reality the situatiion would be more of a proc using quotename and then passing that to another proc that also used quotename. Each fine independently, but when chainge produce a fail.

Comment: Perhaps you could make use of something like `IF(@@NESTLEVEL > 0) BEGIN {scrub} END`

Comment: Actually, I think the selected answer on this post would probably work for you. `set @name = parsename(@name, 1);` [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30302108/what-is-the-opposite-of-the-quotename-function?noredirect=1&lq=1